# How should I define an excel object when I get error 462 VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an issue with a macro that is located in Outlook. The code is triggered by a "Private Sub" code that creates a "TriggerExcel(1)" or "TriggerExcel(2)" which depends of the mail subject.

When the code is triggered it sometimes got stuck at line: `Set ExApp = Excel.Application 'Codes`

Where I get the following Error:

[image]

My guess is that the code doesn't define the excel object correctly in the code, but I have a hard time to understand how this should be made... Any advice or suggestions are much appreciated.

```
Public Sub TriggerExcel(Mode As Integer)

        ‘Activate following tool reference:  Tool-References-Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object library -biblioteket
            Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
            Dim ExWbk As Workbook
            Set ExApp = Excel.Application 'Codes

 cause error here

    ExApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    If Mode = 1 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ExWbk = Workbooks("Nyins.xlsm")
        Debug.Print ExWbk.Name
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\linsten\Desktop\Nyins.xlsm")
        ExApp.Visible = False
        'ExWbk.Application.Run "mymain.main"

        If ExWbk Is Nothing Then
        Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("\\Sca9a\pd-61$\Control\Process\Nyins.xlsm")
        End If

        ExWbk.Application.Run "MainModule.main"

    ElseIf Mode = 2 Then

        Set ExApp = Excel.Application

        On Error Resume Next
        Set ExWbk = Workbooks("Val.xlsm")
        Debug.Print ExWbk.Name
        On Error GoTo 0
        ExApp.Visible = False

        If ExWbk Is Nothing Then
        Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("\\Sca9a\pd-61$\Control\Process\Daily\Val.xlsm")
        End If

        ExWbk.Application.Run "MyMain.Main"

    End If


        ExWbk.Close
        ExApp.Quit
    End Sub
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/178510/excel-automation-fails-second-time-code-runs Perhaps add ExApp to fully qualify Excel objects later in code? e.g. Workbooks("Nyins.xlsm") as ExApp.Workbooks("Nyins.xlsm")

Comment: aren't you missing the "new" statement? Set ExApp = new Excel.Application

Comment: Thank you, I think you are correct. I will try to add New.

Comment: A follow up question, the code is running but when the application is closed it causes Excel to crash. Any ideas what could cause the crash?